# Cant run Machine Learning codes with virtual environment

Tags: python, machine-learning, virtual-environment

im trying to test Machine Learning codes from this site :https://github.com/lyuboraykov/flight-genie
im really new to machine learning and im using windows.

i already installed the requirements to run the code (python, virtualenv, numpy, sklearn, scipy, etc) but i got stuck when i try to run the main code, it shows notification like this :
[image]

please help, thanks

Comment: This question would be better if you showed the folder structure. I doubt this has anything to do with the specific code, just where python looks for modules.

Answer (score 0):

If you run a python script as

```
python dir_name/script.py
```

... then python will execute the file named `script.py` inside the folder `dir_name`. What will happen here is python program will go inside `dir_name` folder first and then run the script.

In your case if you type `python flight_genie/main.py`, it will go inside the folder `flight_genie` and will execute the file. Then python can't find a folder (actually the module) named `flight_genie` there because python program is already inside that folder. That's why you get this error.

So one way of fixing this issue is replacing all `import flight_genie.xxxx` with just `import xxxx`. (Also `from flight_genie.xxxx import yyyy` with `from xxxx import yyyy`)

But it is so time consuming if you have a large project. (And sometime it won't even work). So best way is to run the project as a whole module. 
If you look at [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/) you can see how to run python modules as scripts. You just have to type the following command in console.

```
python -m flight_genie.main
```

ps: I assume that you have `python3` installed in windows and configured to run `python3` when you type `python` in command line.

Answer (score -1):

Have you made installation steps described on author's page? I'm afraid that you didn't read this...

```
sh
# you have to have python 3 installed
pyenv env
source env/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
python flight_genie/main.py
```

Comment: i have, for some reason i cant install pyenv (i guess bcs im using windows) so i installed virtualenv instead

Answer (score -1):

Based on the error message I think your problem is with your import. I'm guessing it should be something like:

```
from flight import Flight
```

Instead of:

```
from flight_genie.flight import Flight
```

If that doesn't work try to post your code so we can try to find the problem.